# C# - 3 Tier Architecture. Error says No overload for method name takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, winforms, 3-tier

I am using 3 tier architecture in my C# Window Form. The thing I want to do is, hide the button if the data is exists. Here are my codes.

**Class File**

```
public bool checkIfExists(Variables variables) { // BelPar
        SqlCommand check = new SqlCommand();
        check.Connection = dbcon.getcon();
        check.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        check.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl";
        SqlDataReader drCheck = check.ExecuteReader();
        if(drCheck.HasRows == true)
        {
            drCheck.Read();
            if (... && .. ||) // conditions where variables are being fetch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        drCheck.Close();
        return true;
}
```

**Window Form**

```
btn_save.Visible = !balpayrolldetails.checkIfExists(); // This is where I get the "No overload for method 'checkIfExists' takes 0 arguments.
```

Any help? Please leave or answer below. Thank you

Comment: The error says it already. You need a parameter (of type Variables) for the function checkIfExists

Comment: Of course, the checkIfExists wants a parameter. Look at your method definition _public bool checkIfExists(**Variables variables**)_ You don't pass a Variables argument

Comment: To simply support calling parameter-less, you can change the signature to `checkIfExists(Variables variables=null)`

Comment: By the way it has nothing to do with 3-tier and it's better to remove it from title, and remove the tag :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a method, you need to call it by its exact name, which in this case is:

```
checkIfExists(Variables variables);
```

This tells us that to use this method, we need to pass it in an object of type `Variables` to be used in the method execution.

Whichever types are outlined in the method signature must be provided to successfully call a method.

You will need to update your call from

```
btn_save.Visible = !balpayrolldetails.checkIfExists();
```

to

```
btn_save.Visible = !balpayrolldetails.checkIfExists(someVariablesOfTheExpectedType);
```

Comment: @Matt-Hensly what do you mean by "someVariableOfTheExpectedType" ? :)

Comment: @mark, that will just be whatever your variables are. You will change it based on the specific variables you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Having the method signature:

```
public bool checkIfExists(Variables variables)
```

It should be called by passing an object of type `Variables` to the method:

```
btn_save.Visible = !balpayrolldetails.checkIfExists(anInstanceOfVariables);
```

But if it's acceptable for you to call the method parameter-less and your method is written in a way that can tolerate having `variables` with `null` value, you can change the signature to this:

```
public bool checkIfExists(Variables variables=null)
```

And then you can call it this way:

```
btn_save.Visible = !balpayrolldetails.checkIfExists();
```